# Open link other then ahref URL

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if this can be done with Javascript or other languages. I have this code on my other site example2.com:

`<a href="http://www.example1.com/page1/">Page1</a>`

When the user clicks this link I want the link to go to the homepage(example1.com) instead of the page1 subpage. However the code should remain intact. Also I don't want any redirects on example1.com or htaccess stuff.

Comment: It's not quite clear what *"... the code should remain intact."* means.

Comment: @10now I'd be interested to know why you want an anchor linking to one address but actually linking somewhere else...it's so confusing that I can't even read my own comment

Answer (score 1):

You can by pass the `href` value by returning `false` in `onclick` attribute

```js
function myFunction(){
  window.location = "http://www.example1.com";
  }
```

```html
<a href="http://www.example1.com/page1/" onclick ="myFunction(); return false;">Page1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me if you have any problem...

```
<a href="http://www.example1.com/page1/" id="plink">Page1</a>  

 <script>
    $("#plink").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr("href");      
        window.location = "http://www.example1.com/";
    });
    </script>
```